# Magmi Shell Plugin Attack?

Tags: magento-1, security, magmi

I have a Magento 1.14 with Magmi installed, so my server notified me that I have an infected with Malware with this message below (it's an encrypted).

> Warning: File possibly compromised: ./magmi/plugins/shell.php
>   (php.malware.generic.040). Manual review recommended.

Is it an attack?

Comment: hey! Did you make the htaccess file for magmi? just recommend to create it and write this code. deny from all
allow from `YOUR PUBLIC IP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite possibly it could be but if the file is encrypted it would be difficult to know.

If you have any concerns about it I would suggest checking file and folder permissions to make sure you have not left yourself open to attacks, change ftp/ssh/user passwords for the server and would also be a good idea to remove magmi and re-download and install it to confirm it is clean. Basically do a bit of a security audit.

Personally i would remove magmi and not put it back but that's because i don't fully trust it and is just my opinion.